# Relationship between convolutions in neural nets and probabilistic convolution

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

In probability theory, convolution extends to produce the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables. I've only ever seen this in the context of univariate random variables.

However, the more general engineering interpretation of convolution is a signal operator/filter. In convolutional neural nets, this seems to be the main interpretation: we can produce common signals throughout, say, an image. But I am wondering if there is a probabilistic formulation/interpretation of this as there is in probability theory? Intuitively I wouldn't think so since I'm not sure how to interpret a 2D convolution probabilistically.